# How much does a Boeing 737 wing bend/deflect in cruise conditions?

Tags: wing, boeing-737, aircraft-structures, cruise

As a part of my ongoing research of a structural joint analysis of a Boeing 737, I have been looking for sources where I may be able to find the bending/deflection data during cruise conditions. I have found sources that may not be considered reliable, however; would anyone be able to assist me with the above data from source that would be considered valid for justification.

Comment: If you can share the sources you have found so far it could help to confirm with any new sources that are found.

Comment: I doubt you will find this information, it's probably considered proprietary of Boeing and not released to the public because the data is likely not required for certification.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv4J1FgQtfM&index=10&list=LLCGHFD1ooc9TX7DUEh0AkPA